# Inserting linebreak between subfigures with active preview package

Tags: line-breaking, preview

I would like to create subfigures with multiple rows with preview mode active. Positioning subfigures sidy by side works just fine:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\usepackage[active,tightpage,floats]{preview}

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{yellow!30!orange}

\begin{figure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
    \centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[fill=red, inner sep=1cm]{Node 1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[fill=red, inner sep=1cm]{Node 2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sufigures side by side]

But when inserting any kind of linebreak to break into the next row it creates a space on the right:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\usepackage[active,tightpage,floats]{preview}

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{yellow!30!orange}

\begin{figure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[fill=red, inner sep=1cm]{Node 1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[fill=red, inner sep=1cm]{Node 2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\vskip\baselineskip %<-- LINE BREAK
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[fill=red, inner sep=1cm]{Node 3};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[fill=red, inner sep=1cm]{Node 4};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Subfigures with break]

It seams that the preview mode generally does not accept any form of linebreak. But maybe someone has a form of solution or hack? Would really help me out!

Comment: you could use a tabular around the subfigures.

Comment: You mean instead of the `subfigure` environments? That definitely works. But I would love to keep the subfigure functionality for captions.

Comment: you can put each subfigure inside a tabular cell

Comment: Boxes (like subfigure) are treated like letters in a sentence (\fussy).  \newline and \par always adds space to the right.  \centering and \\ add spaces left and right.

Comment: Thanks so much Ulrike! Worked like a charm. :) One last problem is the main caption, which does not work when being put in an own tabular row (does not compile). When I put it outside the tabular environment the space on the right reappears. I thought maybe I can somehow store the output of the caption command as a text string in a variable and then just place the variable inside the last row. But did not find a solution for that. Mabye there is also an easier way.